# Elapsed time in seconds, minutes, hours

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I would like to display the elapsed time in a `UILabel` like this:

```
 x sec | when the elapsed time is less than a minute compared to now 
 y minutes | when the elapsed time is less than a hour, but greater than 60 sec compared to now
 z hours | when the elapsed time is greater than 60 sec and 60 minutes, but less than 24 hours +1 seconds compared to now
```

I could successfully catch the elapsed time, but i think it's a different format, because it counts the seconds and minutes differently as i wanted. It shows the elapsed time like this: `-9 min -5 hours -10 seconds`. To make my solution work i would need the second and minute format like this `-120 sec`, if it was 2 min ago or `-120 min`, if it was 2 hours ago, `-48 hours`, if it was two days ago.

I think this solution could be fine, however with the wrong integers I display the minutes or seconds everytime. I would really appreciate if someone could give me some guidence how can i fix the minute & second issue. However if somebody did something like this in the past and knows a better way (or it's a bad way), i would also try it.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:self.fromDate];

NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [dateFromString timeIntervalSinceNow];

NSCalendar *deviceCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];


NSDate *date1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDate *date2 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:timeInterval sinceDate:date1];

unsigned int unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;


NSDateComponents *conversionInfo = [deviceCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date1  toDate:date2  options:0];

NSLog(@" %d min %d hours %d seconds",[conversionInfo minute], [conversionInfo hour], [conversionInfo second]);

if ([conversionInfo second] < 60 || [conversionInfo minute] < 0 || [conversionInfo hour] < 0){

    NSString *secondString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[conversionInfo second]];
    cell.time.text = secondString;

}

if ([conversionInfo second] > 60 || [conversionInfo minute] <= 60  || [conversionInfo hour] < 0){

    NSString *minuteString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[conversionInfo minute]];
    cell.time.text = minuteString;

}

if ([conversionInfo second] > 60 || [conversionInfo minute] > 60 || [conversionInfo hour] >= 1){

    NSString *hourString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[conversionInfo hour]];
    cell.time.text = hourString;

}
```

Comment: don't get it. please clarify your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDateComponent` will always divide you the date into these components. So think of it like you have the Date 31.3.2014 15:08:12 then `NSDateComponent` will deliver you:

```
 day: 31
 month: 3
 year: 2014
 hours: 15
 minutes:8
 seconds:12
```

In case you have a difference these values might be negative, but `[NSDateComponent second]` for example will still just be the seconds part of the time difference and no the whole time difference in seconds format. So if I have a time difference of -4 minutes and -3 seconds, `[NSDateComponent second]` will be -3 and `[NSDateComponent minute]` will be -4.

So in case you want your own description of elapsed time you could use the `timeIntervalSince1970` method of NSDate and compare the UNIX Timestamps directly and calculate the wanted formats, or you use `NSDateComponent` and check against the rules.. So if there is no hour but x minutes.. your elapsed time in seconds is: `numberOfMinutes * 60 + numberOfSeconds` where numberOfminutes is your `[NSDateComponent minute]` and numberOfSeconds is your `[NSDateComponent second]`

So I would recommend you check in the following pseudo code order:

```
if (days > 0) {
   elapsed = hour + minutes/60 + seconds / 3600;
} else if (hour > 0) {
   elapsed = hour*60 + minutes + seconds / 60;
} else if (minute>0) {
```

and so on..

//Disclaimer: no guarantee on the correctness of the provided sample calculation

Comment: I think something like this will work, i also got an idea while reading your answer. It might be work if i check the hours first, if it's less than 1 i check the minutes, if it's less than 1 minute i can display the seconds and so on..

Comment: I updated my answer that you can also see how it works with negative values.. Cause you also need to be sure your if statement checks against the correct thing like jazeee mentioned. Cause checking if hour > 0 makes no sense if I expect hour to be 0 our a negative value.. then of course I would need to check against hour < 0 and so on

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, each value, second, minute and hour are negative.
This means that your comparisons are incorrect.
In other words, you should either use absolute value in the if statements, or you should change your if statements to match your expected values.

Edited:
Your code may be easier to handle if you change your duration to be positive, then simply place a negative sign in the formatted result.
In other words, if conversionInfo is always negative, then switch date1 and date2.
Then when formatting the string, add a minus sign in front of it.

Comment: He wants them to be negative due to his description.

Comment: I think, based on the code and the description, conversionInfo will always be negative, and therefore the first and second if statements will always be true.  The third if statement will always be false.  I don't think that is the intention.  (Why verify that a negative number is less than 60, since it will always be true.)  I suspect that the logic is backwards.

Comment: ah now I got what you intended to mention. Yes this seems wrong, although the logic can be simplified a lot more to also achieve better readability.

Comment: Agreed.  Also, they could switch date1 and date2, and then format as necessary.

Comment: Yes would be more convenient, cause you think of a difference as a positive and not negative value.

Comment: How can i set it to positive? I think i get it like this from the web.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with IOS code, but it looks like you could switch date1 and date2 when you create conversionInfo. In other words, from: date2 to: date1 .  You may want to also rename date1 and date2 to be more clear. Like startDate and currentDate

Comment: It works exactly like jazeee describes. Just switch from and to dates.